# Save cached video on firefox?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, command-line, scripting

I found a script on the internet that allows me to save cached flash files.

https://github.com/janosgyerik/shellscripts/blob/master/bash/save-flash-linux.sh

This would allow me to run the command `saveflash` in a terminal to list flash videos and filesizes. And then I could run something like `saveflash -n 2 nameofvideo.mp4` to save it. I even added the capability to demux the audio out of the video.

I'm trying to do the same for non-flash videos that are cached by firefox. I would like a command, or set of commands that I can run to list the video files and then save them.

It's a little more convoluted. I have to use lsof to list open files, find ones that have a suitable filesize and then get the proc and fd to use for the copy command.

Right now, I do it manually, running a command like this:

```
lsof -c firefox | grep -i deleted
```

The `lsof` command takes a few seconds to complete. And then I have to manually put together the copy command based on what the `lsof` command says that the `pid` and `fd` of the file is, then I would do a command like:

```
cp /proc/3164/fd/55 "~/Videos/Name of Video.mp4"
```

What's the best way to speed up/simplify this process? I'd like to make it into a script eventually.

Answer (score 0):

When you take a look at the mentioned bash script you find the following commands beeing used:

`awk`, `cut`, `cp`, `ffmpeg`, `file`, `ls`, `sed`, `test`, `wc`

You should figure out what they do to automate your manual processing with bash.

Alternative and possible faster ways of getting the `pid`s of firefox is to use `pgrep firefox` or `pidof firefox` which may take less time than `lsof -c firefox`.

Sometimes it's not neccessary to reinvent the wheel. Tools like [youtube-dl](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html) (based on python) are available to download videos from [many video plattforms](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/supportedsites.html).